# Better implementation of custom user navigation

Tags: php, navigation, switch-statement

I have code that generates user navigation depending on a single variable, the users sector id, this is selected when they sign up on the site.

I query the users profile to get the sector id.

With this sector ID I do a massive switch statement (THE PROBLEM) on this sector ID then push values to a navigation array which then makes the navigation.

As I have 40 or more sectors, this switch statement becomes huge and very messy.

Is there a way to tidy this code up? Maybe a MySQL solution or any alternative?

Here is a single case of what I have implemented, imagine it 50 times bigger:

```
switch($sectorid){
 //SECTOR HEADING- SECTORS
    case '9322938ef17ecfe2db3ed25738ed2debca78b9f4':
    case '94ab631f251624ef0a05485961c6f95f38767bbf':
    case '7e0c4c8f07128ea0cc5c5c9884242fcd4565bc72':
    case 'b32dd88a8baf60026fc01e1b0c10fc3371af0880':
    case '2f4d1285c7e0ebe8c448a87142e9d9d5aca0c0a6':
    case '5dc9d9a34c1cd4304c308a9a14189ea01110e85e':
    case '7e3201c9cab00bfe134f0e9277a8bbe16030440d':
    case '949d9ab17fc3f3e5af6db0dfcec6fc7fafa2b11f':
    case 'ef9839efe7b6d780b05fd332ca430a6a8f0c1606':
    case '526cb8abe2b45bb5ead83834310001f683491c0c':
        $key_array = array('catalogue',         'news',         'product_stories',          'staff');
        $url_array = array($d.'catalogue/',      $d.'news/',    $d.'product_stories/',      $d.'staff/');
        $name_array = array('Catalogue',         'News',        'Product Stories',          'Staff');
        break;  
}
```

So yeah, it takes up quite a lot of coding, I think personally its monotonous to do this.

Can anyone see a better way to implement this?

Cheers

Chris

Comment: What's your need to specify a unique user menu for each user? Why don't you use a general menu for everyone?

Comment: Because thats now how my implementation works, multiple users need different features on the site

Comment: Why don't you have for example a MySQL type field in user table, and make the sort through that field?

Comment: I need a solid implementation, been so used to doing it this way that I cant quite figure out what I need to do to get the desired effect

Answer (score 0):

I have sort of an implementation but I'm struggling in one aspect,

here is the proposed database structure:

```
nav_link_table - sector entry

id      sectorid        nav_id

nav_table - nav entry

id      name    key     url     name
```

So i'll be able to add many nav_table fields to a sector within nav_link_table

But the problem is how do I make the order of the nav entries custom to the sector?